# Aierplay-ng, mon0 don't work

Tags: networking, wireless, 15.04, aircrack-ng

I try to install and run aierplay-ng and I have problem with mon0

I've install all what I needed(or I suppose I've do it) but I don't know why when I put that command on Terminal `sudo airodump-ng mon0` it show me a error message:

```
Interface mon0: 
ioctl(SIOCGIFINDEX) failed: No such device
```

or if I try this command  `sudo ifconfig mon0 down` it show me again a error message

```
mon0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
```

Have anyone any idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I've use ubuntu version 15.04

Answer (score 1):

You should first find your wireless interface. Oftentimes it will be wlan0, but use the following command to get a list of your interfaces.

```
ifconfig
```

After finding out what your wireless interface is you need to set it to monitor mode.

```
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
```

Use the name of your wireless interface in place of wlan0. This will enable wlan0 in monitor mode. Using the ifconfig command again you should now see a new interface called "mon0".

If you find you are still getting device not found errors then run the following code to disable your network manager and enable manual changes.

```
sudo stop network-manager
echo "manual" | sudo tee /etc/init/network-manager.override
```

After that you should be able to run the first two successfully.

After you are finished if you wish to restore the network-manager simply run

```
sudo rm /etc/init/network-manager.override
sudo start network-manager
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand my problem, every time when I've used "mon0" with any command I've obtain a error, and I don't know how I can solve it.

Comment: will you post a screenshot or paste the output of the ifconfig command on your computer?

Comment: The mon0 interface is generally your wireless interface put into promiscuous (monitoring) mode. You have to turn on the promiscuous mode of your wireless interface before it will work, however.

Comment: here is my ifconfig output : http://i.imgur.com/A4TEHe4.png

Comment: Yes, try running the command I put above exactly, it should turn monitor mode on your wireless interface and bring it up as an interface named "mon0" After you have run the command please send me the output of ifconfig again?

Comment: here is the output of sudo "airmon-ng start wlan0": http://i.imgur.com/zTWkkYZ.png and output of ifconfig is same

Comment: it seems like you may need to disable your network manager... Here is a link, if you scroll down it will mention how to do it on ubuntu. http://xmodulo.com/disable-network-manager-linux.html
After disabling the network manager try to use the command in my answer again. If it works properly then I will update my answer.

Comment: If it worked for you don't forget to accept my answer please. (:

Comment: I don't test it cause I'm afraid, if I do that maybe I have serious problem with wifi after  and I don't want that

Comment: Undoing those changes is as simple as running  "sudo rm /etc/init/network-manager.override" and then running " sudo start network-manager" The network-manager automatically completes tasks for users so that they don't have to mess with networking much. Doing this override allows you to have more control, and can be easily reset at any time.

Comment: I have error and here, after I used sudo stop network-manager I've received that error: "stop: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused", after I used the next command "echo "manual" | sudo tee /etc/init/network-manager.override"  I've received  back "manual" and the last and most interesting thin is, after I've use "sudo vi /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf" and have to put manager to false, it is already FALSE, why?

Comment: Here is the output of `cat /etc/networkmanager/networkmanager.conf http://pastebin.com/4K2mf1UT. Under [ifupdown] key it shows managed=false, im assuming is the same thing your's says. Here is the relevant section from the manpage, (man NetworkManager.conf) http://pastebin.com/Cq9FqYiY. After reading that I went to see what my default unmanaged interfaces were... heres the what my /etc/network/interfaces file contains. http://pastebin.com/3apbE08M

Since wlan0 and eth0 aren't listed in my interfaces then regardless of whether this is set to true, the network manager would not manage them.